# Placeholders in order method of ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-order-by, rails-activerecord

How do I do this in rails?

```
User.order("abs(height-?)",val)
```

Seems like placeholders are not supported in `order` method, is there some lower level method I can use to process plceholders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be one place where you should actually use string interpolation, but use whitelisting to ensure `val` does not contain anything weird

```
if User.column_names.include? val
  User.order("abs(height - #{val})")
else
  #some error handling
end
```

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that val is not a column name

Comment: is there a way you can specify what values it should hold?

Comment: If val is a number, then the ordering will be the same whether you subtract it from height or not

Comment: my real life query looks like `u.weight_logs.order("abs(extract(epoch from date(?) - log_time))",day).limit(1)` where day is coming from user input. What I probably can do is to cast to to date in ruby, but i was hoping to find a way to use placeholders, which is more universal.

Comment: That could work, otherwise extract the epoch from the date using ruby code, and validate that it is an integral value. Either way you'll have to use string interpolation as far as I know.